# Is there a way to automate creation of pages(and slugs) as and when a record is created in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make a Django website which has all products with all their details(each product has it's own page). However, since there are too many products and they keep changing, I want to automate the creation and deletion of pages according to the database model (models.py).
Am I supposed to use a class based view? Am I supposed to use a function based view with a loop in it?

```py
# models.py
import uuid
from django.db import models
class Brand(models.Model):
  brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
  brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
  brand_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
  # A lot more columns will follow (didn't lock on them yet)
  # This is what I had thought of initially
```

Comment: Please post more details and the example code you are currently using.

Comment: Why are you trying to automatically create an actual page ? If all of your product pages are similar - then 'all' you need is to define a product page template, and using a Class Based View, make the get method render the product page using the template and the data from the Product model.

This tutorial : https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-slug-tutorial covers what you need to do to add product slugs to your model too - Django has a defined 'SlugField' for exactly that purpose.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible in Django. Thanks for the resource and comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do (create product pages automatically), you can override the `save` method in your Products model to create a new Page each time a Product is added, and then use `models.CASCADE` in the foreign key so that if a product is deleted, the associated page is deleted, like so:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
class Page(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      ...

class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
      ...
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.slug = slugify(instance.name)
        page = Page.objects.create(product=self,...)
        page.save()
        super(GeeksModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also use Django signals, like so in your models.py file:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def create_product_page(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
      page = Page.objects.create(product=instance,...)
      page.save()
      instance.save()
```

In your views.py, for example, to get a page:

```
def product_page(request, product_id, product_slug):
    page = Page.objects.get(product__id=product_id)
    ...
    context = {
       'page_data': page
    }
    return render(request, 'page_template.html', context)
```

And in your urls.py for the custom product pages:

```
...
path('/products/pages/<int:product_id>/<str:product_slug>/', product_page, name="product_page")
...
```

So the url would look like:

```
http://example.com/products/pages/3/my-amazing-widget/
```

If you created the link dynamically in a template with something like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <p><a href='{% url 'product_page' product.id product.slug %}'>{{ product.name }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

And there are other ways as well. In the model example above, I included a SlugField you can use to generate the custom URL as well. If you elaborate on your question I can update my answer.

Comment: Seems like having a Page object here is entirely overkill - since all the OP seems to be asking about is rendering a template based on a product information, and that he misunderstands how Django rendering works. I might be wrong but I didn't get the sense from the question that there is more data other than the product information.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your comment. You understood what I wanted to do. I'm sorry I'm not able to add a lot of data as I am not able to figure out the structure of the code myself.
- The Page model is just for dynamically making/deleting pages?

Comment: Glad I could help. The Page model in my code here is for dynamically creating pages but, like someone else mentioned, you can also just use the Products model to render pages in a view, too. Either way works. If you found this useful, please consider up-voting and/or marking it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is - 

- I create a db model which has all my products
- Whenever the admin adds a new record, a new page is created with it's own slug, similar functionality when the record  is deleted.
(Very much like the example url you created)

What kind of information exactly would help you understand this better? I'm really starting out here so pardon the mistakes.
Thank you

Comment: What I added should do that. You can just move the Slug field to the Page model if you prefer.